# php read file looking for string

Tags: php

I'm trying to read a file and look for a specific element within the file.  Once it finds it, I would like the script to add the element to a variable.  So far I have not been able to find anything on this.

This is kind of what I'm looking for:

```
$var = read(($file), "<!--Everything in the comment line-->")
```

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to get out of a file?

Comment: I would like to obtain everything between two points in the file, ex. -start- Make sure you copy me -End- Although in this case I think I have to place the string within an HTML file, That is why my example above had HTML comments.  I plan to place this within a foreach loop which writes all of the found sections to an array variable.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [file_get_contents(…)](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.file-get-contents.php) to read the full file at once and [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.strpos.php) to locate the part of interest, or use a regex if it is something more abstract.